# Automatically assign records after 1 day in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to implement a functionality in MS CRM-
When a user changes a department, record owned by him should be automatically assigned to department owner after 1 day. How to achieve this functionality in Microsoft Dynamics CRM ? By some plugin or workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some type of lookup for Department (1:1 relationship with SystemUser, I would use Power Automate to solve this.

Put the flow on the system user entity, filtered for when column Department changes.  When that happens, use Dataverse connector and pull owner of previous Department, re-assign existing records for types (tables) x, y, z.